# Determining if a file was submitted with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I basically have an edit profile page that along with other fields has a option to upload a picture. Now the problem I have is determining wether or not they submitted a file or left it blank(default).

My current code:

```
if($this->input->post('user_pic') === FALSE)
    {
        //Don't do anything.
    } else {
        //Proccess upload.
    }
```

The form is done correctly with multi-part and all, and other values do update, so I am assuming that this exact code that isn't working.

The problem is that even if I do submit a file it remains just like it was, or another words doesn't do anything. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: If it's a file, it wouldn't be in the `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check so: `if(isset($_FILES['user_pic']))`

CodeIgniter method:

```
$this->load->library('upload');

if ($this->upload->do_upload('user_pic'))
  //good
else
  //errors display $this->upload->display_errors()
```

[CodeIgniter File Uploading Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)